# A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

track - это hash Map.

```
class PointsMaker extends Component {

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  return nextProps.update
}

render() {
    const track = this.props.track;
    const update = this.props.update;

    if (track.length !== 0 && update) {
        this.props.shouldUpdate(false);

          track.forEach((value, key) => {
            if (value.length !== 0)
            return (
              <VehicleMarker target={key}/>
            );

            else return null;
          });

    }
    else {
        return null;
    }


}

}
```

А как по другому можно перебрать массив и выдать компонеты?

Comment: Всё неправильно...

Comment: Твой компонент возвращает много детей <VehicleMarker target={key}/>, а должен возвращать 1-го. Либо заверни всё это дело в другой компонент или в скажем в <div>{track.forEach......}</div>

Comment: `track.forEach` ничего не возвращает, в результате ваша функция возвращает `undefined`. Судя по коду, вы хотите вернуть массив, но это тоже запрещено. Лучше опишите что вы хотели получить.